# Can my brother photograph my wedding as a tourist?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, us-citizens, work, guatemala

I will be getting married in Guatemala. My brother (a US citizen) is an excellent photographer, and I would love for him to take some photos before and after the wedding (he will be in the best man, so can't photograph the actual service).

I have two related questions:

1. Can he legally do this as a tourist? Or would this count as work, and require a work visa even though I won't be paying him?

   [This expats post](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/280/28) says that working for free for an organization that typically charges a salary is not permitted (in the US). It doesn't mention whether the same restriction applies to freelance types of work.
2. Assuming he can do it, can he bring equipment with him as a tourist, or will the fact that he's bringing professional photography equipment<sup>*</sup> as a tourist raise red flags at customs and immigration (that he should either be on a work visa, or that he's importing equipment, etc)?

*This would likely include not only his camera--which is normal fare for a tourist--but reflectors, lighting, etc.

Comment: Wait, you're not paying him? Then he's simply a guest with more freedom to roam around the ceremony, surely?

Comment: @MarkMayo: I *believe* that in some jurisdictions (possibly including the US?), if you are doing a job that would normally receive pay, it doesn't matter that you're not getting paid or not, you are potentially taking away work from a local, so you must have a work permit.

Comment: Wow, today I learned. Carry on then :)

Comment: @MarkMayo: This is new information to me as well, and I'm not sure it's correct (thus the question). If it is correct, then the wedding I shot in Mexico last year may technically have been illegal. :)

Comment: I think you are overthinking this, it is just "_some photos_".

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Until he brings a bunch of lighting equipment into the country with him--then he needs to declare a "professional equipment" exemption, and then the customs officer is going to ask if he's there on business or pleasure. That's really my concern. I was just anticipating a "He shouldn't be taking professional photos at all as a tourist!" response.

Comment: So, if someone loves to take "professional" photos of the wild, will the same rules apply? or he has to ask a local to accompany him to take the photos for him so he gets paid?

Comment: @MeNoTalk: I obviously don't know the answer, but I suspect there's a difference between a wildlife photographer who will be selling his photos "back home," and a wedding photographer who's taking the business of a local. Even so, I wouldn't be surprised if the technically "correct" course of action for a wild life photographer on a photo shoot would be to seek a business/working visa. I imagine that's what photographers for National Geographic, Time, etc, do.

Comment: @MarkMayo: I've updated the question with the reference that made me think it might be an issue... from our good friend littleadv on expats.

Comment: I have seen people making pictures in the zoo with professional gear, simply because they just started a digital photo course. You could use that excuse. Then again, it is a really good question, since bureaucracy can be mad at times. In Belgium, for example, it is considered tax fraud if your friends help you in painting your house.

Comment: @andra: Any photographer knows that the gear doesn't make one a professional. :) Also, what most people think is "professional gear" is really cheap sh*t. In 80% of the weddings I attend, my camera is better than the hired photographer's--and I've never been paid to take a single shot.

Comment: @andra do you have more information about the Belgian tax laws? sounds interesting.

Comment: @jonathanReez Only in Dutch (http://www.vlaanderen.be/nl/bouwen-wonen-en-energie/bouwen-en-verbouwen/bouwvergunningen/hulp-van-familieleden-vrienden-bij-het-bouwen-verbouwen-van-een-woning). It stipulates that family up until second degree ((grand)parents and (grant)children) are allowed to help and the up until the fourth degree (cousins) are tolerated. "Vrienden mogen wettelijk gesproken niet komen helpen" Friends legally aren't allowed to help.

Comment: First of all - congratulations on your upcoming wedding :) - Now, to business - Is your brother a professional photographer, or he is just really good and you would like him to take pictures at your wedding?

Comment: @andra thanks for the link. As far as I understand the reasoning is that people commonly evade taxes by paying "friends" with cash?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: He's not a paid professional. The quality of his work and his gear exceeds that of many "professionals," though.  But his work is in construction and remodeling.

Comment: @Flimzy: "if you are doing a job that would normally receive pay" - I think that is one of the crucial points to answer here. Is taking photos at a wedding considered to be normally a job that would receive pay in Guatemala, or is it common that wedding photos are produced by guests (just like other tasks that are, in some places, often delegated to guests (thus serving as a part of or the whole of their wedding present), such as preparing any parts of the food served during the wedding, or creating any parts of the entertainment program)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a gray area, and to get a definitive answer, you will have to send a complete list of equipment and shooting sites to a Guatemalan lawyer.

Most landscape photographers I know travel around on tourist visa, although this is not completely legal. But they were never caught, mainly because they won't carry that much equipment, since artificial lighting of the Sierra Nevada would require at least one NPP, which falls under the hazardous goods restrictions and exceeds the weight limits. ;)

While a professional photographer, going on vacation with some of his professional equipment, shooting photos for the primary purpose of keeping a memory for himself (and secondary purpose of showing them around to his family and friends), is clearly still a tourist, reflectors and "studio shots" is another thing entirely.

Throw in a room rented/lent for the shots, and you are one step further on the way to "work" - only the "for my relative" and the "not for money" part left to distinguish him from a paid professional.

You should really consider how much risk to take, or whether slightly less professional photos are still good enough for the family album. Is there any requirement for indoor shots with studio equipment?

Comment: We will likely opt for locally purchased/borrowed/rented lighting equipment and/or outdoor shots. We might have been leaning that directly anyway, versus transporting the equipment, but if it's a legal gray area, it's just one more reason not to bother with the transportation of equipment.